# add image to the content of a column in Infragistics XamGrid, Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, infragistics

I am using Silveright 4. I have created a xaml page which has an Infragistics XamGrid. The grid has a column called "status" which has 3 values as: completes, started and ongoing. I want to add an image beside the content in the status column from code behind. 
I have done something like this:

XamGrid1.columns[2].key

but this returs me the column name but not the content. how can i access the content the the column.. please suggest

---

Yes.. I want to put a if else condition on the content of the column. suppose the value is "start" then it shoud have a red flag beside it. and if it  has a value as "completed" then it should have a green flag.. something like this i want to do.

Comment: I suppose you want to access the content of a Cell (i.e. The intersection of a specific Column with a specific Row). Right?

Answer (score 1):

To have an image in the grid cell you will need to either use a Template Columns or a create your own custom column.

If you use a Template Column, you would add the image to the template and you should then be able to use a binding to the value with a converter to get the correct image in the cell.  Refer to [Create a Template Column](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamGrid_Create_a_Template_Column.html) in the help for how to create a Template Column.

If you wish to create a custom column, then you would follow the approach that Devin Rader blogged about in his post titled [Creating Custom Columns for the xamGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2010/07/08/creating-custom-columns-for-xamgrid.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the a sample of the Template Column and the link to the xamGrid doc. In the Converter is where it chooses the image. the converter will return an image if true and if null or false it will return null.

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamGrid_Create_a_Template_Column.html

```
<ig:TemplateColumn Key="ISFAVORITE"
                   Width="auto"
                   HeaderText="Favorite">
      <ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ISFAVORITE, Converter={StaticResource selectFavImageConverter}}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
</ig:TemplateColumn>
```